# how to read notifications coming from our android applicati0on

Tags: android, notifications, widget

I want to update the number of notifications coming from my app to my app widget. I am not getting any idea how to achieve this.

any idea??
Please help..
Thanks in advance

Comment: what you have tried to implement notification in your app ?

Comment: i am developing a chat app.whenever a chat request comes user will get notification

Comment: [See this example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)and please do some Rnd before asking a question

Comment: i know how to create a notification. i want to get the number of notification coming from the app.